# How to remove tabStrip in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabstrip

I want to remove the tab color strip . I tried `setStripEnabled(false);` but that did not work. Also tried `android:tabStripEnabled="false"` in xml code. The tab strip still appears on the tab bar. Can someone tell me how I can remove the blue strip that occurs in the tab bar.

```
JAVA CODE:

public class TabsFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
private TabHost mTabHost;
private HashMap mapTabInfo = new HashMap();
private TabInfo mLastTab = null;

private class TabInfo {
     private String tag;
     private Class clss;
     private Bundle args;
     private Fragment fragment;
     TabInfo(String tag, Class clazz, Bundle args) {
         this.tag = tag;
         this.clss = clazz;
         this.args = args;
     }

}

class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
     */
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }

}
/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Step 1: Inflate layout
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs_layout);
    // Step 2: Setup TabHost
    initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state

    }
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
 */
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

/**
 * Step 2: Setup TabHost
 */
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    Resources res = getResources();
    this.mTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
    TabsFragmentActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", Tab1Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    TabsFragmentActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", Tab2Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    TabsFragmentActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", Tab3Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    // Default to first tab
    this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
    //
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

/**
 * @param activity
 * @param tabHost
 * @param tabSpec
 * @param clss
 * @param args
 */
private static void addTab(TabsFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

    // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
    // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
    // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
    tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
        ft.commit();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
 */
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    TabInfo newTab = (TabInfo) this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    if (mLastTab != newTab) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastTab != null) {
            if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
            }
        }
        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                        newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
            } else {
                ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
            }
        }

        mLastTab = newTab;
        ft.commit();
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

XML Code -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/tabbar_bg"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342818/how-to-change-color-of-the-tabstrip-in-android & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538607/fragmenttabhost-tabwidget-tabstrip-cannot-be-customized

Comment: Found the solution here . Thanks guys http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404907/how-to-set-background-color-tabhost

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your styles xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/LightTabWidget</item>
</style>

<style name="LightTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Simply set child background as null and you have done. For more detail check my answer

```
fragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt("Your tab position").setBackground(null);
```

**Try my answer**
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717362/how-to-remove-the-selected-tab-indicator-from-the-fragmenttabhost/43177274#43177274)