# How to remove the selected tab indicator from the FragmentTabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I have tried several links for remove the selected tab in `FragmentTabHost` but does not work for me .
[First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672302/how-do-i-remove-the-selected-tab-indicator-from-the-tabwidget)
[Second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543478/remove-the-bottom-line-border-in-tab-bar-and-change-selected-color)

I have tried this also in my Xml but it is not working

```
android:tabStripEnabled="false"
```

And it is my layout for the fragmenttabhost.

```
<FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
     />
    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
      android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="@drawable/top_bg"
      app:tabIndicatorColor="#000"
      android:tabStripEnabled="false"
      app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:showDividers="none"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/genralTabBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_1_off" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/treandingTabBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_2_off" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileTabBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_3_off" />

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

And in my devices selected tab look like (Plz check images)

**Moto E device**

[image: Moto E device]

**HTC device**
[image: HTC device]

Answer (score 3):

**Sorry For Late Reply** 
I am also getting this issue and I tried many things on it and finally I get success.

> Try This Below code.

```
 fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1)),
            HomeFragment.class, null);

    fragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackground(null);//set child background as null 
    fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2)),
            CartFragment.class, null);
    fragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackground(null););//set child background as null 

    fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab3)),
            MoreStuffFragment.class, null);
    fragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackground(null); );//set child background as null
```

> fragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt("Your tab position").setBackground(null);

**Simply you have to get child and set it's background as null and you have done**

Comment: ..Thanks for urs reply on it..+1 for your effort...Now i have not any requirement for it...Will test in future(So i did not accept it now....) , when i will do such type of task..Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your +1 and this is my responsibility to post answer and always welcome

Comment: This solution will also remove the onclick Animation.